# cp -u copies all files, not just newer ones

Tags: command-line, usb, bash, backup, cp

I'm `source`ing script that says something like

```
cp -vau /home/jordan/local-directory/ -t /media/jordan/A368-480F/BACKUP/
```

, and that's it. `A368-480F/` is the directory that appears when I plug my USB into my computer. The first time I call this it does what I want and copies over my files. If I call it again immediately without unplugging the USB, the script doesn't say anything and returns, just like it should. If I `umount` the USB, unplug it, plug it back in, and re-`source` the backup script, everything is copied over again, which is not what I want.

I've tried using `stat` on a file in the backup before and after unplugging the USB, but I didn't see any difference. Not sure if this holds for every file that gets copied.

So, my question is, "why is this unwanted copying happening, and how do I make it not happen?".

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: What filesystem is on the USB?

Comment: vfat, according to `mount`. Plus a bunch of stuff in parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that VFAT/FAT32/FAT16/et al... Microsoft's glorious filesystem, only stores file times with a minimum resolution of 2 seconds.  Meaning that if your source file has a mtime of 13:35:47, VFAT will save it as 13:35:46.  Meaning your source file will **always** be newer.

The **cp** command has no mechanism to deal with MS's weirdness, files will always be copied.

To properly deal with VFAT's lossy time storage, I'd suggest using **rsync**.

You gave this cp command as an example:

```
cp -vau /home/jordan/local-directory/ -t /media/jordan/A368-480F/BACKUP/
```

An equivalent **rsync** command would be:

```
rsync -va --modify-window=1 /home/jordan/local-directory/ /media/jordan/A368-480F/BACKUP/
```

This will copy files from src to dest, recursively, copying all attributes as is possible to represent on VFAT. (Permissions, owners, groups, .. well... dang near everything ... doesn't copy to VFAT, just data, and the EVEN timestamps)

The **--modify-window=1** option allows file timestamps to differ by up to 1 second when determining newness.

I like to add the -P (--partial --progress) option, as it allows easier restarting of copy operations, showing a nice progress bar as it goes.

```
rsync -vaP --modify-window=1 /home/jordan/local-directory/ /media/jordan/A368-480F/BACKUP/
```

Of course, rsync allows MUCH more, including copying between systems, snapshotting backups, and others, see the [rsync man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).  My fingers can type *-avzP* as rsync options by themselves I believe.

<sub><sub>No, I am not a fan of VFAT.  NTFS is better, but proprietary.</sub></sub>

Comment: That seems to have done it; thank you, and have a great day!